# Solr popular search terms using Suggester

Tags: solr, search-engine

Referring to the following wiki text derived from the http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester.

"A common need in search applications is suggesting query terms or phrases based on incomplete user input. These completions may come from a dictionary that is based upon the main index or upon any other arbitrary dictionary. It's often useful to be able to provide only top-N suggestions, either ranked alphabetically or according to their usefulness for an average user (e.g. popularity, or the number of returned results)."

How the Solr knows which searched terms are more popular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr doesn't know it by itself, you have to do your part and record all searches made by your users, and feed that to Solr, then, after you have some meaningful usage, you can use it for your suggestions.